# Proof of injective and continuous

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which
>   is strictly increasing in the sense that if $x'<x''$ then
>   $f(x')<f(x'')$. Prove that $f$ is injective and that its inverse
>   function $f^{-1}$ is continuous and strictly increasing.

I know that since $f$ is strictly increasing and $a<b$, then $f$ maps the open interval $(a,b)$ injectively onto the open interval $(f(a),f(b))$, from which it follows that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, but how can I prove this in a more formal manner?

Comment: Try it with preimages of open sets are open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. If $x_1<x_2$, then $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$, and similarly, if $x_1>x_2$, then $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$. It follows that $x_1 = x_2$ and hence $f$ is injective.

Since $f$ is injective, it is invertible on its range $B=f(\mathbb{R})$. Let $f^{-1}$ denote this inverse. Suppose $x_1 < x_2$, and suppose $y_1 = f^{-1}(x_1)$, $y_2 = f^{-1}(x_2)$. We must have $y_1 \neq y_2$, otherwise we would have $f(y_1) = f(y_2)$, a contradiction. We must have $y_1 < y_2$, because otherwise, if $y_1>y_2$, then $f(y_1) > f(y_2)$, again a contradiction. Hence $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing.

Let $x \in B$, and $\epsilon>0$. Let $y = f^{-1}(x)$. Let $x_+ = f(y+\epsilon)$, $x_- = f(y-\epsilon)$. Note that if $x_- < z < x_+$, then since $f^{-1}$ is strictly increasing, we have $y-\epsilon < f^{-1}(z) < y+\epsilon$.
To finish, let $\delta = \min(x_+-x, x-x_-)$. Then if $|z-x| < \delta$, we have $|f^{-1}(z)-f^{-1}(x)| < \epsilon$, hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

**Aside**: I left out a minor detail above. Since $f$ is strictly increasing, it follows that $B$ is open (since $\mathbb{R}$ is open). When showing continuity of $f^{-1}$, the $\epsilon$ must be taken small enough so that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset B$.

Answer (score 1):

1) let $x\not=y$, we may suppose that $x<y$, then $f(x)<f(y)$, henca $f(x)\not=f(y)$. This shows $f$ is a injective.

2) **Note that $f$ is open then $f^{-1}$ is continuous.** Note that $f$ is open iff for every open set $U$, we have $f(U)$ is open. Note every open set $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ is the union of some open interval $(a,b)$. Therefore, to prove $f$ is open, we only need to prove for any interva $(a,b)$, we have $f(a,b)$ is open.

> **Claim: $f((a,b))= (f(a),f(b))$**

Proof: on one hand, $f(a,b)\subseteq (f(a),f(b))$ is obviously as $f$ is strictly increasing. On the other hand, let $x \in (f(a),f(b))$, then $f(a) < x<f(b)$, we have $a < f^{-1}(x)<b$, thus $f^{-1}(x) \in (a,b)$, and hence $x \in f((a,b))$.

Comment: @Q.matin: You are welcome.