# Differentiable function with discontinuous inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am looking for an example of a bijective function $f:(a,b)\to\Bbb R$ which is differentiable on the entire interval $(a,b)$, but has a discontinuous inverse.

Comment: It's not possible, even if you merely assume that $f$ is continuous. See the answers to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362080/proof-of-injective-and-continuous).

Answer (score 1):

I think this result implies that $f^{-1}$ must be continuous.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Answer (score 1):

Here are two intuitive concepts that help resolve this search.

First, if a function is differentiable, then it must be continuous.  In some sense, you can think of a continuous function as one whose graph can be drawn with a pencil without ever having to lift it from the paper.

Second, the graph of the inverse of a function is obtained by reflecting the original graph across the line $y=x$.

With these two ideas in hand, notice that if you can draw a graph without having to lift your pencil, it makes sense that you will also be able to draw its reflection in the same way.  Thus, its reflection should also be the graph of a continuous function, so that $f^{-1}$ is indeed continuous.

We conclude that there is no bijective differentiable function whose inverse is discontinuous.

Comment: While very helpful, this is of course a very dangerous kind of argument

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: You're right.  Perhaps I shouldn't use the phrase 'we conclude', because I don't really prove anything in my answer.  My point was just to help develop intuition.